# Gradle select language

Tags: gradle

I use the command:

"gradle init"

but select implementation language option doesn't seen.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjoMj.png)

Comment: The default is Groovy. If you pressed enter, and didn't type anything, that's what it'll use. What's your actual question?

Comment: But there sould be "Select implementation language" option which I want to choose java, but it does not seen

Comment: Answered below.

Answer (score 0):

The option is asking what language you want **`build.gradle` and related files** to be in.

The only supported options for those are Groovy (default) or Kotlin.

If you want to then use Gradle to manage a Java project, for example, then you will need to [add the `java` plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html) to your `build.gradle` file.